# I Want to Show only The Dates from a MySQL Database Between Today and the Next 30 Days

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following Code:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `test_establishments`
 WHERE expiry_date > CURDATE() AND expiry_date < CURDATE()+30
```

The Query returns 0 Rows and I do have dates in the database that expire within the next 30 days. I am not sure what the problem is with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
select * 
  from `test_establishments`
 where expiry_date between curdate() and curdate() + interval 30 day
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=00163ea00b336c6e7f043bde37f077af)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `+` on a datetime. You need to use `DATE_ADD` instead.

`DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), interval 30 day)`

Answer (score 1):

Use this code 1 month or 30 days.

```
WHERE expiry_date > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
AND expiry_date < NOW() + INTERVAL 30 DAY
```